# Websocket location mismatch when Safari 5.0 connects via nginx https proxy

Tags: nginx, socket.io

On an older version of Safari, when I connect to my socket.io, I get an error:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: location mismatch: wss://domain.com/node/socket.io/1/websocket/id != wss://localhost:81/node/socket.io/1/websocket/id
```

The newest versions of Safari seem to work fine.  I can connect fine with firefox and chrome.

The server-side code is:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(81, {resource: '/node/socket.io', secure: true});
```

The client-side code is:

```
socket = io.connect('https://domain.com/', {resource: 'node/socket.io', secure: true, 'connect timeout': 1000});
```

I'm routing this through nginx with:

```
location /node {
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
}
```

How can I fix this error and get it working with older versions of Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx websocket proxy only works for RFC6455 compliant handshakes. The older draft 75/76 handshakes, found in Safari 5 and old versions of chrome can't be proxied through nginx. Some more details here: [Nginx: Reverse proxying WebSocket Draft 76](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361639/nginx-reverse-proxying-websocket-draft-76/16490369)

Answer (score 0):

Nginx **does** support **draft76 based websockets**. It is indeed unaware of what is the websocket protocol version used between your client and the server. All what matters for him is whether it must ["Upgrade" the connection or not](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/changeset?old=e14b49c12a73d0586357d1d8a1b3c55618e14c13&old_path=nginx/src/http/ngx_http_upstream.c&new=7fa7e60a7f66f62b6ff6d071d9425d5b7a454f19&new_path=nginx/src/http/ngx_http_upstream.c).

Here the thing is that [draft 76 websockets with socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9/lib/transports/websocket/default.js#L116) require to have a **matching protocol and location** between the client and the server, which is the error you get here. This comes from the fact there is no correct HOST header set in your proxy configuration, making *socket.io* uses "*localhost:81*" instead of "domain.com" as host.

```
location /node {
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass https://localhost:81;
}
```

**Note:**

Both *protocol* and *location* must match so you must also proxy to your socket.io server using the same protocol the client used.